# ERROR - unexpected token when getting bigger JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, token

I have a textbox that takes user input, sends it to WS, where it searches for anything matching said data and returns all that it finds as JSON. Then I take said json and fill a table. If the user input is quite specific I get the data and table is created with no problems, if the user input is not specific I get quite a lot of data in my JSON, BUT I also get ERROR - unexpected token, and the table stays empty.

My js

```
$('#btnFilter').click(function () {
var filter = $('#txtFilter').val();
var sqlCall = ""
    callJsonWs("EXECUTE procedure", "loadPageFilter");
});


function loadPageFilter(dataJSON) {
var data
try {
    data = JSON.parse(dataJSON)
}
catch (err) {
    alert("ERROR - " + err.message)
}
document.getElementById("tableFilterPopup").innerHTML = ''
$.each(data.filter, function (index, value) {
    document.getElementById("tableFilterPopup").innerHTML += '<tr onclick="newLocation(\'' + value.pageView + '\')">'

                             + '<td>' + value.jobCode + '</td>'
                             + '<td>' + value.jobCustomerName + '</td>'
                             + '<td>' + value.jobPhoneNumber + '</td>'
                             + '<td>' + value.jobModel + '</td>'

                         + '</tr>';
})
}
```

Comment: Is your JSON well formatted? Did you try JSON.stringify(dataJSON) before calling JSON.parse(dataJSON)?

Comment: Yeah, it's well formatted and I did try JSON.stringify(dataJSON) but I still get the error.

Comment: The error says that it is not valid JSON that you're getting back. Can you paste the JSON string that throws the error into jsonLint.com and see if it validates. Perhaps somewhere in the return string there is an escaped character something like --  "here\'s what I\'m talking about" -- This would be fine in a normal string but in JSON you have to escape the escape character so it would have to be -- "here\\'s what I\\'m talking about".

Comment: You were right, the JSON wasn't valid. When the search was being processed in SQL taking vague user input returned multiple conflicting datasets messing up JSON format, thankfully my database guy figured out how to fix it. Thanks for recommending me jsonLint.com, first time using it and will use it in the future quite often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gregg Duncan has mentioned, the problem was with invalid JSON format that broke off hence I was getting an incomplete JSON string.